# Persistent Browser Extension Reinstalls Itself: How to Eradicate ‘YOfficeStop’ Permanently on Windows 7?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, obfuscation, malware

I’m struggling with a browser extension named ‘YOfficeStop’ that persists across all browsers on my Windows 7 system. Despite deleting the source and uninstalling browsers, it reinstalls itself upon every restart. I’ve checked startup processes but found nothing suspicious. Below is the manifest.json of the extension:

```
JSON

{
  "name": "YOfficeStop",
  "version": "6.89",
  "description": "Office Stop",
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/",
    "management",
    "notifications"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon128.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "minimum_chrome_version": "35"
}
```

files are located at C:\ProgramData\Bvtl\Uyfnruq\AACB5D4D:

```
[Tags]
ExtName=YOfficeStop
ExtVer=6.89
ExtDesc=Office Stop
UserId=18ae074a616ecc94f30f67e696f6a58f
```

[background.js](https://pastebin.com/N7E1ZZ2h), [svcworker.js](https://pastebin.com/hgnWe2Yh).

Comment: Run some anti-virus software on your computer - the obfuscated code, plus that `C:\ProgramData\Bvtl\Uyfnruq\AACB5D4D` folder all point to some sort of malware IMHO

Comment: See https://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Chrome-Extensions-Installed-by-Administrator